# What is the JSON body content when calling RSA's REST Initialize method for On-Demand Authentication?

Tags: rest, rsa

According to RSA documentation, https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-76775, to have a token sent to a user for authentication, the user enters their username and ODA pin, then an email will be sent to the user with the token to authenticate.

Assuming all the hardware and servers are set up correctly, what is the JSON body content that needs to be sent to have the token emailed?

If we send an Initialize, by itself, we cannot specify a pin:

```
{
  'clientId':'myClientId',
  'subjectName':'user123',
  'context':{
    'authnAttemptId':'',
    'messageId':'messageId',
    'inResponseTo':''
  }
}
```

If we send an Initialize and include the pin in the subjectCredentials, we get a VERIFY_ERROR:

```
{
     'clientId':'myClientId',
     'subjectName':'user123',
     'subjectCredentials': [
        {
            'methodId': 'SECURID',
            'collectedInputs': [
                {
                    'name': 'SECURID',
                    'value': 'usersODAPin'
                }
            ]
         }
      ],
      'context':{
        'authnAttemptId':'',
        'messageId':'messageId',
        'inResponseTo':''
      }
}
```

What is the JSON body content that needs to be sent to have the token emailed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there really was a server configuration error.

So, the successful and correct way is the later:

```
{
     "clientId":"myClientId",
     "subjectName":"user123'"
     "subjectCredentials": [
        {
            "methodId": "SECURID",
            "collectedInputs": [
                {
                    "name": "SECURID",
                    "value': "<user ODA Pin>"
                }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "context":{
        "authnAttemptId":"",
        "messageId":"messageId",
        "inResponseTo":""
      }
}
```

And then follow it up with a proper Verify post with a body like so:

```
{
    "clientId": "myClientId",
    "subjectName": "user123",
    "subjectCredentials": [
        {
            "methodId": "SECURID_NEXT_TOKENCODE",
            "collectedInputs": [
                {
                    "name": "SECURID_NEXT_TOKENCODE",
                    "value": "<user pin and token>"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "context": {
        "authnAttemptId": "<authnAttemptId from initialize call>",
        "messageId": "messageId",
        "inResponseTo": "<messageId from initialize call>"
    }
}
```

And remember to have the following headers:

```
content-type: application/json
client-key: <your access key>
```

Since there was such a lack of information on the web about this, i'll leave the post up for a while.  If it gets no activity or votes to delete - i'll delete it.